# Paginación con máximo 10 páginas

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy realizando un sitio web que me muestra un catalogo de artículos pero quiero que en pantalla no me muestre mas de 10 por ejemplo, y que el usuario pueda navegar a través de un menú como este
[image: Menu Google]

Nunca he realizado algo asi y no he podido encontrar ningún tutorial en la web como para guiarme.

Cualquier tutorial o al menos como se le dice a dicho menú agradecería bastante.

Comment: Se llama *`Paginación`*  y lo puedes hacer tú mismo mediante reglas CSS o con un framework. Sugiero que revises [`ente ejemplo hecho con Bulma`](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/pagination/), Bulma es un framework super ligero y muy sencillo. Si exploras su propia página, podrás hacer cosas como las que hay en ella. Hay muchos usuarios que se han lanzado a crear plantillas gratuitas basas en `Bulma` ([mira aquí algunas para diferentes estilos de sitio](https://dansup.github.io/bulma-templates/)).